# protect AIR app code using certificate?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I try to develop app, where user could download encrypted media. User have to login before, then he will receive key to decrypt media. Communication base on AMFPHP & SSL cert. The problem is:
Somebody can decompile main .swf, grab decrypt key and algorithm (it's impossible to prevent from decompile). The solution coluld be send class after user authentication. I have read somewhere that it's possible to load classes dynamicaly from web (but can't find good excample), and call only public method in main .swf, so algorithm wil lstay unknown. 
 1. Does this metod safe? Does 'bad guy' can simulate my app i.e. call method and grab classes?

Mentioned method based on grab code from original app, and simlate it to capture datas, after connection secured by SSL. Every AIR App requied to be exported with certificate.
 
 2. Can I use application certyficate in connection? I mean, can I use this cert to ensute that application that call method is this generated by me. If it's possible, can someone can share link, or code how to do this?
 3. What if somebody will try to manually overwrite main .swf on device, with his grab version. Does OS validate some checksum and will block, or accept false .swf as original?
 4. I can't find documentation that derscribe mechanism of using application cert in AIR (only how to generate it, and diffrence between self-signed, and commercial). Does somebody find article witch describe more about using cert on iOS, or Android?

I woluld be glad for other information how to protect communication in AIR app.

Answer (score 0):

Load classes from web: read about 'runtime shared libraries'
1. Why not generate a unique 'key' for each authenticated user? Don't recycle the same one.
2. 3. and 4. I think the 'cert' is used for installation not afterwards. If you build your own key / cert process you can ignore 'fake' apps.

Comment: It think, it doesn't matter if key will be uniqe. Even if, user can grab his own key, decrypt content and publish it on i.e. torrent. Using encryption with salt, and send uniqe key part, is useless until I can't hide decryption algorythm contain salt string.

Comment: Use a public / private key pair. Have your app retrieve the appropriate key(s) when needed. Also - since it's an AIR app you can use the client MAC address as a salt if you want to encrypt that way.